# Proving that $H_{n}(X,A)$ is isomorphic to $\widetilde{H}_{n}(X)$ if A is acyclic.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I encountered this exercise in Bredon's book "Topology and Geometry". I managed to prove the case where $n>1$ using the exact sequence of the pair $(X,A)$ and the property that relative homology is isomorphic to homology of the same space for dimension higher than 1 but I am not sure how to continue. I would prefer hints over the full answer please.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just consider the fragments
$$\cdots \to\widetilde{H}_n(A) \to \widetilde{H}_n(X) \to H_n(X,A) \to \widetilde{H}_{n-1}(A) \to \cdots $$
of the (reduced) long exact sequence of the pair $(X,A)$. Bredon mentions the reduced version of the long exact sequence in page 185.

Answer (score 1):

There is a map of pairs $(X,\ast)\to (X,A)$ which induces a map between long exact sequences of pairs. The maps associated to $1:X\to X$ and to $\ast\to A$ are isomorphisms. Now use the 5 lemma to conclude that $H_*(X,A)$ is isomorphic to $H_*(X,\ast)=\widetilde H_*(X).$

Comment: Could you elaborate on what this long exact sequence of pairs is?

Comment: @NoelLundström If you have a pair $(X,A)$ of topological spaces, there is a long exact sequence of the form $\cdots H_n(A) \to H_n(X) \to H_n(X,A) \to \cdots$, which is functorial from pairs to long exact sequences.